# If variance is $\mathrm E[(X-\mu)^2]$, then what is $\mathrm E[X-\mu]$?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics, central-tendency

The question is pretty straightforward.

The variance of a random variable $X$ with mean $\mu$ is defined as $\mathrm E[(X-\mu)^2]$ and is notated $\operatorname{Var}(X)$ or $\sigma^2$.

Another measure of central tendency could be defined: $\mathrm E[X-\mu]$. I’d simply like to know if this has a name. If not, that’s okay.

Comment: $E[X-\mu]=0$. The name is zero :-)

Comment: @KaboMurphy Oh snap . . . have I missed something obvious here?

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish May be, absolute value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathrm{E}} \E[X-\mu]=\E[X]-\E[\mu]=\E[X]-\mu=\mu-\mu=0$. I have used the fact that expectation is linear  and expectation of a constant is the constant itself.